# Spark with Cassandra SaveToCassandra

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra-2.0

I'm using Cassandra with spark, and I have a `JavaRDD<Srring>` containing 6 columns separated by `,` like this:

```
header: canal,action,time,tiemend,client
```

I have created a table `Mytable` with 6 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ref_event_by_user_session (
    canal       TEXT,
    action      TEXT,
    time        timestamp,
    timeend     timestamp,
    Client      INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(canal, action, time, timeend)
);
```

and now I want to save my `JavaRDD` in my Cassandra table using `javaFunctions().saveToCassandra`,
but I don't know how to use it. Could you please show me how to do it?

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md

Comment: Why people voting down this question? I see the value in this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution. 
If it can help someone :) 
I just create a java class `table2` with `canal String,
    action      String,
    time        Date,
    timeend     Date,
    Client      String,`

and then :

```
JavaRDD<Table2> table2 = session_7.map(new Function<Tuple2<KeyTable2, ValueTable2>, Table2>() {
       @Override
       public Table2 call(Tuple2<KeyTable2, ValueTable2> keyTable2ValueTable2Tuple2) throws Exception {
           SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
           Date startdate = formatter.parse(keyTable2ValueTable2Tuple2._1.time.replace("+","."));
           Date endtdate = formatter.parse(keyTable2ValueTable2Tuple2._1.endtime.replace("+","."));
           Table2 t = new Table2(keyTable2ValueTable2Tuple2._2.canal,keyTable2ValueTable2Tuple2._2.motif,startdate,endtdate,keyTable2ValueTable2Tuple2._1.client);
           return t;
       }
   });

    javaFunctions(table2).writerBuilder("Schema", "Table", mapToRow(Table2.class)).saveToCassandra();
```

Note : you must add the getters in the class even if the differents variables are public.